# Symfony2 - Forced to validate inside DataTransformer because of type hint on setter

Tags: mongodb, validation, symfony

I have created an Object to ID Data Transformer.  It's part of a custom ObjectIdType that allows me to enter the ID of a document instead of using a 'document' form type.  It's handy for MongoDB (when there could be 100 million documents to choose from).

The Data Transformer does a query upon the ID and returns an object.  If it can't find an object then it returns null.  The issue is - sometimes null is an acceptable value, and sometimes it isn't.

Even if I add a NotNull validator, I get the following error -

*Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Character::setPlayer() must be an instance of Document\Player, null given*

So it's calling the setter regardless of the validation failing.  I fixed this by throwing a TransformationFailedException within the transformer - but this just seems like a bad idea.  I shouldn't really be using a Data Transformer to validate.

The code of the transformer is below.  What I'd like is to be able to put the validator in the correct place, and intercept the setter so it doesn't get called.  Generally, this seems like a bit of a code smell, I would love to know how other people have solved this issue.

```
class ObjectToIdTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $objectLocator;
    private $objectName;
    private $optional;

    /**
     * @param ObjectLocator $objectLocator
     * @param $objectName
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectLocator $objectLocator, $objectName, $optional = false)
    {
        $this->objectLocator = $objectLocator;
        $this->objectName    = $objectName;
        $this->optional      = $optional;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function transform($value)
    {
        if (null === $value) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!$value instanceof BaseObject) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException("transform() expects an instance of BaseObject.");
        }

        return $value->getId();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        if (null === $value) {
            return null;
        }

        $repo = $this->objectLocator->getRepository($this->objectName);
        $object = $repo->find($value);

        if (!$this->optional && !$object) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException("This is probably a bad place to validate data.");
        }

        return $object;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it's a PHP quirk that's very unintuitive — especially for those coming from other (logical, intuitive, sane) languages like Java. If you want to be able to pass a `null` argument to a typehinted parameter, you have to set its default value to `null`:

```
public function setPlayer(Player $player = null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Yea, talk about some consistency here...

Comment: Oh, I didn't want the null value in the setter at all, it's been removed on purpose because null isn't a valid option.  Do you think I should allow null and then let the validator handle it?  I hadn't considered that because my getters and setters are strictly set up to mirror whether the underlying property is nullable or not.

Comment: Yes, you should allow the `null` value and let the validator handle it.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Honestly, I think that's somewhat of a workaround, but I don't think there is a better way.  I would prefer it if there was some way of intercepting the submitted value before it's applied to the object via the setter, but I think that's just a limitation of Symfony.